# What is the usual sorting method for numeric citation?

Tags: biblatex, sorting

What is the usual sorting method for numeric citation?
If it is not 'none', then in the text the citation will appear in a strange order.

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more detailed I think, it's not at all clear what you mean or what you are asking.

Comment: The question of numeric-style vs authoryear citation call-out styles is completely independent and separate from the question of how the entries are sorted (e.g., alphabetical by authors' surnames vs in the order the entries are cited in the body of the document) in the bibliography.

Answer (score 2):

In `biblatex` you can choose the style independent of the sorting (the latter is controlled by the `sorting` option, see appendix C *Default Sorting Schemes* of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for all standard sorting schemes).

By default, `biblatex`'s `numeric` styles use the `nty` scheme - they sort by name, title and year. That means that the bibliography at the end will be ordered that way, but of course citations do not just count from 1 to n as we read through the text.

`sorting=none` on the other hand sorts the citations by appearance.

Of the three (maths) papers with numerical style I found on my desk, two used `nty` sorting and one `none`. I couldn't say if one is much more prevalent than the other and so would qualify as the "default".

It is a matter of taste (or requirements) what to choose, but with `biblatex` it's very easy to change the sorting if you change your mind.